# Does every port have a unique specification?

Tags: networking, port, port80

Hello i am wondering if every port have a unique specification like for example does port 80 transfer HTML texts fast?
Thanks for any answer

Comment: There's *a lot* of history to port numbers, their "meaning" and usage, so let me ask the following: are you asking in the context of a particular programing problem? TIA.

Comment: i was trying to make django website and server and then was thinking what if i dont use port 80

Comment: I'm not as familiar with django, so I'm using a comment vs. an answer... but most modern frameworks, like this, default to 80, but will work on any reasonable port number. A lot of people like 8080 because it is easy to remember, and it unofficially was the port web proxies used. I would avoid 443 if the listener is not using encryption/SSL, that is the default port for `https://` URLs. Some applications will hard-code certain ports, but there is rarely a technical sound reason for that.